# Count from 2 tables based on one-one, many-one, and many-many relationship

Tags: mysql

I have a query in Mysql and I'm here to seek your inputs.

I have 2 tables T1 and T2 in mysql.

Both contain a common id column with values as shown below -

```
T1 - 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5
```

and

```
T2 - 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5
```

I am trying to query table T1 to give me output in the following manner -

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5
```

If one-one relationship exists between T1 and T2 as in value 1, 2, 5 then it is selected from T1. If many-one relationship exists between T1 and T2 as in value 3 in T1 which has one value in T2 then only one value is selected from T1. many-many as in value 4 in T1 and T2 is selected as it is from T1.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read the initial question.  What about a one-many relationship, where `T1` includes `6`, and `T2` includes `6`, `6`?

Comment: No worries:-) In one-many relationship, the only value 6 is selected from T1. Random seems to have cracked it below.

Comment: You may want to restate that as part of your question.  Also, @Random's answer won't work for that case.

Comment: Fair enough. We've got huge data in both tables and the query is taking forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T3.ID FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM T1) T3
INNER JOIN T2 ON T3.ID = T2.ID
```

It collapses the results from T1 into a distinct set, then re-inflates it based on matches found in T2.